# React Native error logging with firebase Crashlytics - How to get javascript stack trace

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics, react-native-firebase

I have a React native application with configured using react native *firebase lib* and added the module of *Crashlytics*. 
Everything works okay but when i try to log an error using `recordError()` method or when i just use `crash()` its just logs errors in the dashboard in native form. I tried to find a way of getting js error to the dashboard but so far nothing has worked.

---

Is this possible or i should try a different way?
maybe another platform like 
bugsnag or sentry?

Comment: Tried [reading through this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480099/unable-to-find-meaningful-logs-for-reactnative-using-crashlytics)?

Comment: @JakeSteam Hey thank you for replying, yeah but it mentioned about react-native-fabric-crashlytics not firebase crashlytics.

Comment: I know that in version 6 of rn-firebase package added functionality of javascript stack traces, but this version is in alpha. Also I have an article about this topic, but didn't checked if this method still works with version 5.x.x of rn-firebase crashlytics: https://medium.com/delivery-com-engineering/add-crashlytics-to-your-react-native-ios-app-69a983a9062a

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me and showing javascript `stacktrace`:

```
....
catch (error) {
    crashlytics().recordError(new Error(error));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [react-native-exception-handler](https://github.com/a7ul/react-native-exception-handler) to get a js stack trace for the crash and also send js stack trace to firebase crashlytics

like this

```js
import {getJSExceptionHandler} from 'react-native-exception-handler';


setJSExceptionHandler((error, isFatal) => {
  if(isFatal)
  {
  crashlytics().recordError(new Error(error));
  }
});
```